# Compile time "null" using forward declaration?

Tags: c++, pointers, compilation, compiler-errors, forward-declaration

I'm facing a problem using forward declaration, and I don't know how to fix it. Here's my files:

**BubblePlug.h**

```
#ifndef _BUBBLEPLUG_
#define _BUBBLEPLUG_

#include "IPlug_include_in_plug_hdr.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "IControl.h"

class IPianoRoll;
class IMidiEngine;

class BubblePlug: public IPlug
{
private:

public:
    IMidiEngine *pMidiEngine;
    IPianoRoll *pPianoRoll;

    BubblePlug(IPlugInstanceInfo instanceInfo);
    ~BubblePlug();
};

#endif // !_BUBBLEPLUG_
```

**BubblePlug.cpp**

```
#include "BubblePlug.h"
#include "IPlug_include_in_plug_src.h"
#include "IPianoRoll.h"
#include "IMidiEngine.h"

BubblePlug::BubblePlug(IPlugInstanceInfo instanceInfo) : IPLUG_CTOR(10, 1, instanceInfo) {
    pPianoRoll = new IPianoRoll(this, 8, 8);
    pMidiEngine = new IMidiEngine(this);
}
BubblePlug::~BubblePlug() { 
    delete pPianoRoll;
    delete pMidiEngine;
}
```

**IPianoRoll.h**

```
#ifndef _IPIANOROLL_
#define _IPIANOROLL_

#include "IMidiEngine.h"

class IPianoRoll : public IControl
{
private:
    BubblePlug *pBubblePlug;

public:

    IPianoRoll(BubblePlug *bubbleplug, int x, int y) : IControl(bubbleplug, IRECT(x, y, x + 10, y + 10)), pBubblePlug(bubbleplug) {

    }
    ~IPianoRoll() {

    };

    bool Draw(IGraphics *pGraphics) {
        return true;
    }

    void Random(bool onlyScore = false) {
        pBubblePlug->pMidiEngine->Init();
    }

    void Start() {

    }
};

#endif // !_IPIANOROLL_
```

**IMidiEngine.h**

```
#ifndef _IMIDIENGINE_
#define _IMIDIENGINE_

class IMidiEngine
{
private:
    BubblePlug *pBubblePlug;

public:
    IMidiEngine(BubblePlug *bubbleplug) : pBubblePlug(bubbleplug) {

    }
    ~IMidiEngine() {

    };

    void Init(bool randomScore = true) {
        pSamplwhk->pPianoRoll->Start();
    }
};

#endif // !_IMIDIENGINE_
```

when I ***compile***, it says around `pSamplwhk->pPianoRoll->Start();`:

```
use of undefined type 'IPianoRoll'
left of '->Start' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

VS2015 find each element writing the code (I've no problem), it happens only when I compile (Build).

Why? I pass `BubblePlug` and I do forward of both `IPianoRoll` and `IMidiEngine`, including them in order (on `BubblePlug.cpp`).

`IMidiEngine` should know everythings about `IPianoRoll` (which it is included first).

At least, I should have problem at "runtime", why at compile?

Can you help me to understand the problem and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `#include "IMidiEngine.h"` to IPianoRoll.h

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0: I've edited the question. Check it out!

Comment: Unrelated: Your include guards are illegal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPianoRoll.h includes IMidiEngine.h, so no matter in which order you include the two files, the definition of IPianoRoll will always come after the `init` function where it is being used.

One way to avoid this is to move the body of the `init` function into a separate .cpp file:

In IMidiEngine.h:

```
void Init(bool randomScore=true);
```

In IMidiEngine.cpp:

```
void IMidiEngine::Init(bool randomScore) {
    pSamplwhk->pPianoRoll->Start();
}
```

Comment: Now I see what's the problem. Since it add "once", IPianoRoll become always after IMidiEngine. So IMidiEngine don't know IPianoRoll's Start method, right? Why spearate files will fix the problem? That's what I don't udnerstand. At compile time first if include .h, than "compile" .cpp?

Comment: You must make sure the definition of a class is seen before you are allowed to use it. My suggested solution does this: it moves the function body to a later point in the compilation, where both definitions have already been seen by the compiler.

Comment: @paizza - In the .cpp file *everything* is included first - so visible in the function bodies. In a header file you cannot see what comes in the next header.

Comment: Now it starts to make sense why there are .cpp and .h files :)